# Authorization problem with SharePoint ClientContext created with ADAL Access Token

Tags: sharepoint, token, adal, csom, unauthorized

I am trying to automatize the provision of a SharePoint Online Site Collection. I am doing it with SharePoint CSOM. If I create the ClientContext(Microsoft.SharePoint.Client) object 
with SharePointOnlineCredentials, everthing works fine such as creating sub sites/list/libraries, upload custom master pages, setting web properties etc. *(By the way we are using Publishing Site)*

```
ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(contextWebUrl);

SecureString sec_pass = new SecureString();
Array.ForEach(contextPassword.ToArray(), sec_pass.AppendChar);
sec_pass.MakeReadOnly();
ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(contextUserName, sec_pass);

return ctx;
```

But i don't have user's password on production environment because we have to use ADAL authentication and we have only **Access Token**. So i have to create ClientContext object by using this token. Like;

```
ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
ctx.ExecutingWebRequest += delegate (object sender, WebRequestEventArgs e)
      {
           e.WebRequestExecutor.WebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + siteToken.AccessToken);

           if (digestValue != null)
            {
               e.WebRequestExecutor.WebRequest.Headers.Add("X-RequestDigest", digestValue.FormDigestValue);
               e.WebRequestExecutor.WebRequest.Accept = "application/json;odata=verbose";
            }
       };
return ctx;
```

by this way *getting* something from SharePoint works but if i try to *_set_* something such as create a subsite or deploy a master page to *catalogs library* i am getting 401 as below.
**Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource**

I thought that it was an update issue but even though i have used *X-RequestDigest* nothing changed.

Some people have encountered same issue when uploading documents but all answers are about using rest api directly and this cant solve my issue.

Answer (score 1):

The token which is being used in second method is related to **application client Id**.

So Azure application needs necessary permission as similar as user's. In Azure Portal/Azure Active Directory, i gave AllSites.FullControl permission to the application which i use to signin and get access token.

Hereby this problem has been resolved.